# Unexpected namespace prefix "wallet" found for tag fragment

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments, android-pay

I am trying to integrate Stripe into my android app using Android Studio. This is my payment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:wallet="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="me.cm.ap.Payment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/wallet_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    wallet:enviroment="test"
    wallet:fragmentMode="buyButton" />
```

So at the code above, I'm getting an error at

```
wallet:enviroment="test"
wallet:fragmentMode="buyButton"
```

that says "Unexpected namespace prefix "wallet" for tag fragment..."

I have already added

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
```

to my gradle module, aswell as

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
        android:value="true" />
```

to my manifest.

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you didnt add play services add there lines and rebuild:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:9.4.0'
```

After than, If you still have that errors change payment layout like this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:wallet="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/wallet_fragment"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.fragment.SupportWalletFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
wallet:environment="test"
wallet:fragmentMode="buyButton"/>
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I didn't have play services wallet added at first, but that didn't solve the problem. I tried using your fragment code too, but still same error at wallet:environment and fragmentMode. Even though those lines are underlined, I can run the app, but I can't click the android pay button.